# Entity relationship diagram | A dealer sells a car to a customer

Tags: entity-relationship

I can't figure out how to modelise the following situation into a ERD :

A car dealer sells a car to a client.

I suppose there are 3 entities here (without considering the atttributes):

1. The seller
2. The client
3. The car

The relationships are the following (without considering the cardinalities) :

1. The relationship **sell** between *seller* and *car* represents in the real world that the dealer sell a car
2. The relationship **owns** between *car* and *client* means in the real wold that a car is owned ny a client

HERE The ERD I have made:
[image: Seller Sells Car, Client Owns Car]

I think that what I have made means **A dealer sells a car and a car is owned by a client** but I wanted to schematize that **A dealer sells a car TO a client** and the information meant by the **TO** is lost in my ERD.

How is the best way to schematize it ?

I know this sounds stupid, but I am not familiar with ERD,

Anyway thanks for your help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about a ternary relationship?

[image: Seller sells Car to Client]